# Cannot fill up blank space with Linear layout

Tags: android

I am designing a screen using linear layout.The screen looks like:

[image]

As you can see after the last layout some whitespace is coming up and I am not able to remove them.

The code:

```
        <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menu_absent_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/message"
                    style="@style/BodyStrong"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/default_store_message"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/navigate_default_menu"
                    style="@style/BodySmall"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/default_menu"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/profile_allergies_chart"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_65_opacity"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_box"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/navigate_location"
                    style="@style/BodySmall"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/location_search"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/profile_allergies_chart"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_65_opacity"
                    android:background="@drawable/fav_box"
                    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/sub_menus"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroundwhite"
                android:padding="2dp" />

            </FrameLayout>
```

Please note that there is also a recycler view.BUT it is hidden.I don`t think that it is the reason of the problem.

How do I remove the white space and make the linear layout to take the remaining space?

Edit: Changing Frame layout width to **match_parent** is not working

Comment: I think it's no whole layout. If `match_parent ` in framenlayout doesn't work, there must be something in level upstairs frame, what lock it.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the parent `FrameLayout attributes`

**from**

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

**to**

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Your `FrameLayout` is on `wrap_content`

Try this:

```
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your framelayout to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to fill up all the space vertically and then do any other changes needed so that the nested layouts look nice.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `FrameLayout` `height` attribute from `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

As `wrap_content` only occupy the space needed for your `content` not whole `activity` space.

```
              <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
```

Change:-

```
              <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
```